# Permanently adjusting RHEL 6 timezone

Tags: rhel, date, timezone

We have a collection of cards running RHEL 6. We would like them to boot such that their timezones are Zulu (UTS, GMT, GMT-0). I have read and tried many of the suggestions out there that supposedly deal with this issue.

Editing `ZONE` in `/etc/sysconfig/clock` to read Zulu
pointing the `/etc/localtime` link to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Zulu`
running `system-config-date` as `root` and selecting `UTC`.

All of these work during the session but after a reboot we're back to AST as the timezone.  It's kind of maddening and I'm losing patience regarding where to look and what to try (been futzing with this all day).

If this has been covered already somewhere, please point me to that magical place. If not, any ideas of what else to try?

Comment: do these hosts use DHCP or static addressing?

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s1-utc_timezones_and_dst

Comment: https://tecadmin.net/change-timezone-on-centos-and-redhat/

Answer (score 0):

It could be solved by crontab using:

```
# crontab -e

    @reboot /root/localtimechange

# vi /root/localtimechange

    unlink /etc/localtime
    ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Zulu /etc/localtime

# chmod +x /root/localtimechange
```

It will run `/root/localtimechange` script that will change your timezone to Zulu automatically after reboot.

To see what is linked to `/etc/localtime`, use `ls` command:

```
# ls -l /etc/loc*
```

Reboot and try this command again to see if it changed.

Additionally, if you have incorrect time shift, you could install `ntp`:

```
# yum install ntp ntpdate
```

Then update your time:

```
# ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

And set the hardware clock to the current system time:

```
# hwclock --systohc
```

You could add the last two commands to `/root/localtimechange` script if required to apply them after reboot.

**Important:** If you're working remotely, temporarily change `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file first uncommenting and changing string under `# Authentication:` line:
`LoginGraceTime 2000m`

to avoid possible ssh disconnects and loosing ability to connect through ssh:

> ```
> LoginGraceTime
> ```
>
> The server disconnects after this time if the user has not
>   successfully logged in. If the value is 0, there is no time limit. The
>   default is 120 seconds.

In case you'll be able to change settings locally, you could comment this parameter and check if it is possible to connect and work through ssh.